# how to unlock upgrades for the MEC soldiers

Tags: xcom-enemy-unknown, xcom-enemy-within

I'm on my first play through of enemy within and currently have a MEC unit and am aware that you can upgrade them using the rank, but I was wondering is there a way to either unlock additional armors for the MEC warriors or is there any upgrades that I can get for them in the foundry?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can unlock [stronger](http://xcom.wikia.com/wiki/MEC#MEC-2_Sentinel) [suits](http://xcom.wikia.com/wiki/MEC#MEC-3_Paladin) (more armor HP, bigger will bonus, extra equipment) by researching [UFO Power Source](http://xcom.wikia.com/wiki/UFO_Power_Source_%28Project%29) and [Titan Armor](http://xcom.wikia.com/wiki/Titan_Armor_%28Project%29).

Several Foundry projects also benefit MEC Troopers:

- [Shaped Armor](http://xcom.wikia.com/wiki/Shaped_Armor)
- [Advanced Servomotors](http://xcom.wikia.com/wiki/Advanced_Servomotors)
- [Jellied Elerium](http://xcom.wikia.com/wiki/Jellied_Elerium) if using Flamethrower
- [MEC Close Combat](http://xcom.wikia.com/wiki/MEC_Close_Combat) if using Kinetic Strike Module
- [Ammo Conservation](http://xcom.wikia.com/wiki/Ammo_Conservation)
- [Alien Grenades](http://xcom.wikia.com/wiki/Alien_Grenades) if using Grenade Launcher
- [Improved Medkit](http://xcom.wikia.com/wiki/Improved_Medikit) if using Restorative Mist

Comment: This is first time that I've actually bothered with the Alien Grenades project... before MECs came along I just stole them off Mutons ;-)